# Material3 MaterialToolbar disable coloring at scroll

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, material-components-android

I am migrating my app to `Theme.Material3.*` and found that the `MaterialToolbar` is now being highlighted in some accent color as soon as some content scrolls underneath it. See the animation that I'm referring to below:

[image: Screenrecording]

However, I don't want this effect to be present within my application. But while reading through the [MaterialToolbar documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/appbar/MaterialToolbar), it seems like there is no way to disable or modify it, which irritates me. What am I missing here?

The minimal XML layout to reproduce the behaviour (as well as using a [Material3 theme](https://material.io/blog/migrating-material-3)):

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:liftOnScroll="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:titleCentered="true"
            app:title="Welcome"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="noScroll" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
   
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..." />

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, after playing around a while, I'm going to share my findings.

The background color animation takes place at scrolling only when the attribute `app:liftOnScroll` is set to `true` in the `AppBarLayout`.

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/primaryAppbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:liftOnScroll="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/primaryToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

When setting `app:liftOnScroll="false"`, the Toolbar will permanently show the highlight color. This then can be changed by setting the `android:background` attribute.

In case you have a Layout containing two AppBars, and you want both to show the animation at scrolling, you can synchronize them by calling [addLiftOnScrollListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/appbar/AppBarLayout#addLiftOnScrollListener(com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout.LiftOnScrollListener)) like so:

```
primaryAppbar.addLiftOnScrollListener(new AppBarLayout.LiftOnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(float elevation, int backgroundColor) {
        secondaryAppbar.setElevation(elevation);
        secondaryAppbar.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
    }
});
```

In this case, `primaryAppbar` is the one receiving the scroll events.

Answer (score 1):

If you use jetpack compose, all types(`CenterAlignedTopAppBar`, `MediumTopAppBar`, `LargeTopAppBar`) of `TopAppBar` have parameter `color`. We can use it to set correct color for scrolled `TopAppBar`.

If you would like to use default colors, but change only scrolled color:

```
colors = TopAppBarDefaults.centerAlignedTopAppBarColors(
    scrolledContainerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface
),
```

Full code of `TopAppBar`:

```
CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
    title = {
        Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.teams))
    },
    colors = TopAppBarDefaults.centerAlignedTopAppBarColors(
        scrolledContainerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a style for toolbar.

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    style="@style/Widget.Material3.Toolbar.Surface"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="noScroll"/>
```