# Flutter Material3 disable appbar color change on scroll

Tags: flutter, material-ui

Using Material3 `useMaterial3: true` in Flutter version 3.0.1, when scrolling lets say listview, the appbar changes to darker color... Can this be disabled?

Example from native android [Material3 MaterialToolbar disable coloring at scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71214120/material3-materialtoolbar-disable-coloring-at-scroll):

[image]

Comment: Why would you want to change a standard material 3 behavior?

Answer (score 124):

I had same problem.

In my case i had an `AppBar` with transparent background and a `Scaffold` with `extendBodyBehindAppBar` set to `true`.

I tried with `shadowColor` and `surfaceTintColor` with `Colors.transparent` value, but the shadow was still visible.

Then I noticed the `scrolledUnderElevation` property of AppBar. Setting it to 0.0 was the solution.

Comment: I confirm setting `scrolledUnderElevation` to `0` also works for me to solve the issue.

Comment: Worked for me as well 

Comment: Saved me couple of hours

Comment: This did work for me as well.

Comment: but with this solution i am not able to cast a shadow below the appbar :-/

Comment: great work man . thanks!

Comment: Damn!!! How did you find this solution????? It works like a charm. At first, I thought it was caused by my incorrect UI structure. It took me a whole day to solve it!!

Comment: To Improve on this answer instead of adding `scrolledUnderElevation: 0` to every `AppBar`. You can add the following line inside your theme: `appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(scrolledUnderElevation: 0),`

Answer (score 49):

I think you can just set the `surfaceTintColor` property of `AppBar`:

```
surfaceTintColor: Colors.transparent
```

I was facing this same issue and solved it right after looking at your question.

Comment: for me it worked with Colors.white

Comment: thanks! But for me it also worked with Colors.white

Comment: not working for me :(

Comment: thanks, this work for me. Just add this into Theme

Comment: didn't work for me, it shows a light black shadow. `scrolledUnderElevation` worked well.

Comment: This is what I needed to stop the colour change but also maintain the shadow. Note that the shadow itself can be changed with the shadowColor property!

Answer (score 22):

I think this is the best solution mostly with the material3 flutter

```dart
scrolledUnderElevation: 0,
```

to disable it completely just make sure it is 0 incase you just want to reduce the opacity just increase the value i.e 0.6

Answer (score 7):

Best solution is chage the following property `AppBar`

```
scrolledUnderElevation: 0
```

Answer (score 7):

```
appBar: AppBar(
      scrolledUnderElevation: 0.0, // This will fix the problem
      title: Title
    ),
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 4):

just add below property to AppBar :

```
forceMaterialTransparency: true,
```

problem will solved.

Comment: this is the most underrated answer!!

Answer (score 3):

Overriding `defaultScrollNotificationPredicate` of an `AppBar` also seems to reach the desired behavior, i.e:

```dart
AppBar(
    notificationPredicate: (_) => false,
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
surfaceTintColor: Colors.transparent;   // add required color
```

Either add in the `appBar` or otherwise in the `ThemeData`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the AppBar's property `surfaceTintColor: Colors.transparent,` to disable the "recoloring".

You can set it as a property of the `AppBar` widget for each app bar.

Or better yet, override the `surfaceTintColor` in the `AppBarThemeData` property of `ThemeData` when setting the global theme of the app. This way you can set the property for all AppBars in your app.

Answer (score -1):

use  surfaceTintColor: Colors.yourColor,

Answer (score -1):

surfaceTintColor: Colors.transparent;  This works for instead of adding to every appbar of page add it in appbar

appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
surfaceTintColor: Colors.transparent,
),