# Strange background color appbar flutter

Tags: flutter

Hello I updated my app to material 3 and a strange appbar color show on the background when I scroll. Does anyone know how to remove it and leave it always white? Thanks!
[image]
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72379271/flutter-material3-disable-appbar-color-change-on-scroll does this help?

Comment: Yes that's it! Thanks!!!

Comment: [Solution here, its a duplicate post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72379271/flutter-material3-disable-appbar-color-change-on-scroll)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Material3 disable appbar color change on scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72379271/flutter-material3-disable-appbar-color-change-on-scroll)